# Listings inside tabularx table?

Tags: tables, listings, tabularx

I'm doing a very long `sidewaystable` with `tabularx`. The thing is that I have a lot of text in columns:
[image: Table 1.]

I did it using `minipage` and `enumerate`. The thing is that I was wondering if there's any way I could **get the last column on the top of it (same start point as third column)**. Heres my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
.
.
\begin{document}
some text here..
.
.
\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{2.5cm} p{3.5cm} X X }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Índice}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fórmula}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ventaja}}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Contras}} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{-10}[2]{1in}{\normalsize{\textbf{NDVI} \\[3mm] {\small Normalized Difference Vegetation Index \\[3mm] \citep{Rouse1973}}}}
        & \multirow{-10}[8]{1.5in}{
        \begin{equation*} 
            \frac{NIR_t-RED_t}{NIR_t+RED_t}
        \end{equation*}}
        & 
        \begin{minipage}{3.3in}
        \begin{enumerate}[{-}]
          \item ....
          \item bla bla...
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
        &
        \begin{minipage}{3.3in}
        \begin{enumerate}[{-}]
          \item ....
          \item bla bla 2...
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

To be honest, I'm really new at LaTeX. So I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you fixed typos in your code (e.g., `\bagin` instead of `\begin`) and made the code compilable (by loading all required packages, among them `multirow`, `natbib`, and `amsmath`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of two new packages: `makecell` for column headers and multi row cells and `paralist` for compact lists. Package `mathtools` (the same result can be obtained by use of `amsmath` package) serve only for `\text{...}` command in one column header. Probably it will somewhere else in report. With this I made the following table:

[image]

with code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
%    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}%

\usepackage{paralist}%enumitem
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \small
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5in} 
                             >{$}p{1.2in}<{$} 
                             X X }
\toprule
\thead{Índice} 
    &   \thead{\text{Fórmula}}
        &   \thead{Ventaja}    
            &   \thead{Contras}     \\
\midrule
\multirowcell{1}[-17em][l]{
    \large\textbf{NDVI}     \\[2ex] 
    Normalized Difference   \\
    Vegetation Index        \\[2ex]
    \cite{{Rouse1973}}
                            }   
    &   \multirowcell{1}[-19em][c]{\dfrac{NIR_t-RED_t}{NIR_t+RED_t}}   
        &  \begin{compactitem}[$-$] 
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item  ...
            \end{compactitem}
        &      \begin{compactitem}[$-$]   
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item  ...
            \item  ...
                \end{compactitem}   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
    \end{document}
```

Package `lipsum` serves for dummy text only. I comment `microtype` package I haven't installed scalable fonts. Also I comment `babel` and to it related package for the same reason. This changes shouldn't destroy obtained result.
Beside this, I slightly simplified provided MWE.

Note: Instead of `paralist` can be used newer `enumitem` package, however it  differently determine distance between items and between itemize environment surroundings (top and bottom of cell).